# Wait if certain condition is met?

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, httpurlconnection

I'm not sure if my approach is the right one so I'll give my best to describe the problem as good as possible.

I'm programming a client that connects to a server. It sends out some (different) request frequently. Somewhen it might happen that there were too many requests so I'm forced to re-login.
The login is verified by a token that is set in the request header.

I'd like to implement something like a lock / wait object. Most of the requests run in separate threads but send the (final) request via the same function. Right in this function I check the response for validity and if the server decided to kick me, I send the re-login request.

My problem: If there's an invalid response, I re-login asynchronously (JavaFX Callbacks for the response) and continue. 
Due to the multithreaded tasks there might be a condition where 2 (or more) requests get the same invalid response and try to re-login or one task tries to execute a request while another one is logging in (so there's no valid token), receives an invalid response, starts to login while the other one receives a valid login, that one gets invalidated during the new login and so on.

How can I force my tasks to wait until the login requested by another one is finished? What would be the best approach for that?

Thanks and sorry for the grammar!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a case of accessing shared resource. Your intuition with lock/wait is correct. A synchronized method seems like a good solution for you. If it's not, use [Semaphore](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How should I implement this wait-thing? if (loginFlag) obj.wait(); and in my loginProcedure loginFlag = true & at a successful login obj.notifyAll? I'm on my mobile, sorry for lack of formatting

Comment: Yes.. Keep a bool flag - "reLogin" which is set to false. If the server kicks you, you have to change it to true and notify all the waiting threads...The other thread(s) will be waiting for this..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a central class in charge of your login, you could use re-entrant locks to manage this:

```
private final ReentrantReadWriteLock loginLock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

public boolean isLoggedIn() {
    loginLock.readLock().lock();
    try {
        return loggedIn;
    }
    finally {
        loginLock.readLock().unlock();
    }
}

public void login () {
    loginLock.writeLock().lock();
    try {
        if (!isLoggedIn()) {
            performLogin();
        }
    }
    finally {
        loginLock.writeLock().unlock();
    }
}
```